# How to change size of dots?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I want to make grid of dots, but I'm not sure this is the right way to do it.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
img = Image.new("RGB", (1000,1000), (0, 0, 0))
 
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(i)
w, h = img.size
step = 100
 
for n in range(step,w,step):
    for x in range(step,h-step,step):
        draw.point((n,x), fill="yellow")
img
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass a size parameter to point, so try ellipse:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
img = Image.new("RGB", (1000,1000), (0, 0, 0))
 
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
w, h = img.size
step = 100
size = 10
for size in [1,25]:
    for n in range(step,w,step):
        for x in range(step,h-step,step):
            draw.ellipse([n-size/2,x-size/2,n+size//2,x+size//2], fill="yellow")
    img.save('size_{:d}.png'.format(size))
```

Which gives the following outputs:
[image: Size 1 png]
[image: Size 25 png]